# Can you describe the following python opencv function in details?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

here, "image" is my input image.
I want to process the image to get my required output.
The code is running perfectly. But i am not understanding the problem in details.
I just want to understand the function theoritically line by line

```
def points(image,e):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
    lower = np.array([0,0,255-e], dtype=np.uint8) 
    upper = np.array([255,e,255], dtype=np.uint8) 
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower,upper) 
    a = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image, mask= mask)
    a = cv2.cvtColor(a, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return a
```

Comment: Although you might get answers, please try to understand that stack overflow is **not** a replacement for the many documentations that are already present.  Before you ask a question, please try to do your own research. Stack overflow should be the last place to ask stuff like this.

Comment: If you pass a low value for `e` (say less than 10), it will select only the the very brightest whites and light greys. If you increase `e` (say 100), it will select more pastel colours and slightly darker midtone shades. As `e` approaches 255, it will select nearly all of your image including the darkest and most saturated colours.

Answer (score 0):

`Line 1:` You define a function receiving two arguments: `image` and `e`.

`Line 2:` The input image is first converted from `BGR` to the `HSV` color space.

`Line 3:` You create a `lower` threshold value containing three values for each
`HSV` channel – `H: 0`, `S: 0`, `V: 255 – e`.

`Line 4:` You create an `upper` threshold value containing three values for each
`HSV` channel – `H: 255`, `S: e`, `V: 255`.

`Line 5:` You create a binary (the pixels in the image are **either** black or white) `mask` where all white pixels on your (converted to `HSV`) input are the ones that fall between your specified threshold, for all three (`HSV`) channels.

`Line 6:` You `AND` your binary mask and your original input. That is, all the black pixels on the mask will be used to "turn off" all the corresponding pixels on your original input. All white pixels will remain "on", for all three (`BGR`) channels.

`Line 7:` You convert the resulting image from `BGR` to `grayscale`.

`Line 8:` You `return` the resulting image.

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful & organized answer. Can you please describe the works of augment "e" in this function?

Comment: Well, I suppose `e` is a scalar value (i.e., a number) hard to know without the context of your code, but `e` is a number that it is used to define your `upper` and `lower` thresholds. For the lower threshold `e` is subtracted from 255 on the V (value) channel. In the upper threshold it is assigned directly to the S (saturation) channel.

Comment: @Tanbir `e` is passed to `points()` as second parameter, so you can find its meaning and/or its value just checking what it represents inside the code section calling `points` in order to be executed